# Direct3D 11 with DirectDraw (2d) overlay

Tags: directx, direct3d, direct2d, directdraw, direct3d11

Basically, I want to do 2d drawing on a 3d swapchain. But my code injects in another program, with I don't have the source code.

I can do my drawing, but it only works when the swapchain is created with DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM (BGR) format.

Originaly, the program uses DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM (RGB), and when I switch it to BGR, the program renders offside the window/screen. Almost everything is larger.

Is there a way to interop Direct3D 11 with 2D using RGB or a way to make the application rendering works correct with BGR?

Comment: My code to draw 2d on 3d swapchain is based on this example: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/552795-solved-d3d11-and-direct2d/

Answer (score 0):

If the swap chain is created with the DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM format then you just need to make sure that the Direct2D bitmap properties that you pass to the render target’s CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface method also specifies the same DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM pixel format.

Comment: But accordingly to the URL I said and my tests, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT is required for Direct2D interoperability.

Comment: Yes, this flag is required but it does not mean that the swap chain format needs to be BGRA. I realize it’s a bit confusing but Direct2D supports more than just BGRA pixel formats.

Comment: CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface seems to be Windows 8 API. I'd like a Vista/Win7 API.

Comment: It is supported by on Windows 7 with the DirectX platform update.